# Cannot load assembly error

Tags: windows-7, windows

I installed windows 7 32 bit for a friend, his laptop is hp 2000-2d07ee. I installed all the drivers I could find [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4062&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=5451237). I ran windows update, I installed .net framework 4.5 and  Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4. I still see this error

[image]

Do I need to install an earlier version of .net framework or C++ Redistributable, or is there another way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what HP forums ([1](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Wireless-Internet-Home-Networking/HP-Connection-Manager-Problem/td-p/1900855), [2](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Wireless-Internet-Home-Networking/HP-connection-manager/td-p/1156433)) say:

- if you have a Windows with 3rd party themes and `uxtheme.dll` patched this may cause the problem. You'll have to revert to original files.
- check if it is in the startup list (run `msconfig` and look in the **Startup** tab)
- install Microsoft .NET Framework version **3.5 SP1**
- you should reinstall HP Connection Manager. The latest version is 4.5 and you can find it [here](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp64001-64500/sp64316.exe). Restart your computer after that.

Comment: I think it worked

Answer (score 0):

In case people have issues with the HP Connection Manager (HPCM) when Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 is installed, you can get the later version of HPCM here: [HP Connection Manager](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=ob_164776_1) then go to the **Revision History** to see if even a newer version is available.

I bumped into another issue with HPCM 5.0 after rebuilding HP EliteBook 840 G3 with Win7 Enterprise x64.